# What's the correct name for the data structure (object) representing collection of GPS tracks

Tags: language-agnostic, gps, naming-conventions, ooad

I want to implement, for personal use, an object representing a structured collection of GPS data.

Currently, there are a lot of file formats to represent this data, all of them with some minor variation of this representation:

- A trackpoint would be a 4 element tuple representing the fixed-ordered sequence `(latitude, longitude, elevation, timestamp)`.
- A tracksegment is a sequence (ordered collection) of trackpoints, ordered by timestamp, representing a continuous line.
- A track is an ordered collection of tracksegments, ordered by "creation timestamp", representing a discontinuous line (or multiple continuous lines in a given order).

My question is: "from a object-oriented design good-practices point of view, how should I name a class to represent a (not necessarily ordered) COLLECTION OF TRACKS"?

For example, suppose I have a GPX file, a KML file and I want to save both to a single JSON file, the API calls would be:

```
kmldata = new GPS_Data("somefile.kml");
gpxdata = new GPS_Data("somefile.gpx");
merged = GPS_Lib.merge(kmldata, gpxdata);
merged.save_to_json("somefile.json");
```

I feel that "GPS_Data" is too broad.
Also, this would be the structure usually serialized to a file, but "GPS_File" refers too much to implementation of persistence, but this is an incidental use of the object (serialization to disk), not the definition of it.

Comment: For the interested, interesting concepts can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you store  tracks in a List of Track.
So you can call it Tracks or TrackList.

More generally, you simply use the plural word for the element of that collection:
singular: "track"
plural "tracks"

In java this would be

```
List<Track> tracks.
```

Comment: I'm inclined to say that this is a very valid response to my question... Just as a side-question: supposing I include also "Waypoints" and "Routes" (two other standard concepts in the field) to that collection, so that it contains no more only Track objects, but a (not necessarily ordered) set of an arbitrary number of Tracks, Routes and Waypoints intermixed, what name would you give then? (this is being very enlightening to me, thanks beforehand!)

Comment: then GpsData, GeoData, AppData, NavigationData, NavigationItems but this then depend if it represent all of the user's recorded data, or a only a subset.

Comment: I'll go with GpsDataSet, since Tracks, Routes and Waypoints are pretty much all the primitives a GPS device might give, and the properties of their elements can be extended if needed. I think DataSet (in the sense of a `Set<GpsObject>`) better conveys the idea of finitude and specificity. Thanks again!